# How do I pass the clipping parameter for the export request in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, image

Starting at ArcGIS Server 10.8, for map services using the ArcGIS Pro runtime, the [export](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/export-map.htm) request now supports the **clipping** parameter to clip the image produced, according to the geometry included in the clipping parameter.

This works fine when I test it manually (e.g. Either through the ArcGIS REST Services Directory for the export request, or by using Postman). The image is clipped. However I need to do this clipping within a web application using the [ArcGIS API for Javascript 3](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/).

For instance for the [ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) I see no obvious way to input this **clipping** parameter. Neither directly or through some other configuration. Is this possible?

If this is not currently supported in the ArcGIS API for Javascript 3, is there a way to hack in some extra parameters when the API makes **export** requests? So that I could manually set this clipping myself?

Comment: Good workaround, you should add that as an answer instead of an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting and found that I could hack in some extra parameters by adding them to the private _params property of the layer.

This works, the image is clipped.

This may break in the future since this **_params** property is not really supposed to be accessed directly like this, but until the API supports this it does the job for me. Also I confirmed that the clipping won't work for map services using the ArcMap runtime, it needs to use the ArcGIS Pro runtime.

Also a detail that may or may not be important to you (e.g. if you're using a proxy) is that since the clipping geometry would be too long to fit in the URL as a query parameter, the API will use a POST request to do the **export**, instead of the usual GET request.

Ex:

```
const layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(url, options)
layer._params.clipping = JSON.stringify({
     geometryType: 'esriGeometryPolygon',
     geometry: {
     rings: [[[382057.1446,5390601.6059],[382057.2633,5390601.4493],[382057.3779,5390601.2897],[382057.4883,5390601.1272],[382057.5946,5390600.9619],[382057.6965,5390600.7939],[382057.7941,5390600.6234],[382057.8872,5390600.4504],[382057.9758,5390600.275],[382058.0599,5390600.0974],[382058.1394,5390599.9177],[382058.2142,5390599.736],[382058.2844,5390599.5525],[382058.3497,5390599.3672],[382058.4103,5390599.1803],[382058.466,5390598.9919],[382058.5169,5390598.8021],[382058.5628,5390598.611],[382058.6038,5390598.4189],[382058.6398,5390598.2257],[382058.6708,5390598.0317],[382058.6969,5390597.8369],[382058.7178,5390597.6416],[382058.7338,5390597.4457],[382058.7447,5390597.2495],[382058.7505,5390597.0531],[382058.7513,5390596.8566]]],
     spatialReference: { wkid: 32188, latestWkid: 32188 }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add extra parameters to a subset of layer requests in the 3x API, you could also use the esriRequest.setRequestPreCallback(callbackFunction) method.  It allows you to fully modify the requests and their properties.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest.setrequestprecallback